# Metaplex Storefront v2?

Tags: untagged

Metaplex Storefront v1 had been depreciated and everyone is waiting for v2. But will v2 really solidify and be released? Or a complete change of direction of Metaplex to focus on smaller projects?

Answer (score 1):

In regards to a metaplex storefront V2 you can check out this Discord post here
https://discord.com/channels/848060988636921856/849017184901922838/996897394383912982

Metaplex have annouced that a storefront v2 is no longer on the cards and are focusing more on shipping SDKs and other components that allow access to programs.